# What is best practice for handling & designing mongo collection in MongoDb in .NET core for a complex scenario?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have mongoCollection in which data is uniquely identified by the three parameters we pass in the url (getData/A/B/C) . Now, the requirement has been modified and the user can send 'A' field blank to identify a row, like getData/B/C. But however our c# code enforces we have all the three fields, what would be the best practice to handle such scenario? Should we create a new mongoDb collection where store data separately for data to be identified by B/C?

Comment: In general, the uniqueness constraint is enforced in the database by having (creating) a Unique Index. So, if there are three fields, and together enforces uniqueness, its likely that there is a unique index on the three fields (index on multiple field is called as Compound Index).

Comment: Does this mean that B & C alone are unique or are there cases when you have several A values for the same B & C values? Especially, if you have a document for B & C with a blank A, can there be additional documents for the same B & C with values for A?